# Problems while installing Microsoft entertainment pack on 3.11

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ssd, windows-3.1

I am trying to install Microsoft Best of Entertainment pack on windows 3.1x with 32mb RAM 1GB SSD space and 70% of a intel core i7-1165g7, using Virtualbox on windows 10.

1. First i tried doing it via MS-DOS (then booting into windows)

> A: setup

**This program requires Microsoft windows**
Then i noticed A: is not where Windows is so :

1. Boot into windows copy the setup files onto the C drive

> C: setup
> Once again

**This Program requires Microsoft windows**
Then i tried:

- Booting into windows 3.1x
- Opening MS-DOS prompt and trying the same 2 things
  **This program requires Microsoft windows**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After start Windows 3.1 start File manager, found where your `setup.exe` is located, go to this directory and double click on the file.